# how to read and extract internal links in document with python

Tags: python-3.x, templates, ms-word, hyperlink, internals

i have source word document, having some internal links, I have task to pull relevant info from source file and paste on template file, while doing this internal links are not coming.you're copying content from one Word document to another, including templates, and internal links (such as bookmarks, hyperlinks, cross-references, etc.) are not being copied correctly,

Comment: What have you tried so far?